# highcharts line not showing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I'm creating some visualisations using HightCharts. Thought series only for a specific year I automatically draw a line between actual value for the bar and the result-target.

I draw the line in this way:

```
{
      dashStyle: 'dash',
      lineWidth: 2,
      shadow: false,
      zIndex: 2,
      color: '#000e3e',
      data: [[0, 5], [3,3]],
        name: 'Line for Project 2 - Results'

    }
```

on the data part I specify to start from column 0 which is first year and 3 which is the Results.

The problem is that in HightCharts when there's more than one value for a year the line doesn't start from the top of the bar but from the middle.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Is there any possible way to start drawing line from the top of the bar?

Here's the [JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6kLjzudm/#&togetherjs=Kelcp03LPB)

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'Combination chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['2014', '2015', '2016', 'Results']
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Project 1',
        data: [10, 4, 1]
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Project 2',
        data: [5, 4, 5]
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Project 3',
        data: [2,8, 3]
    },{
      dashStyle: 'dash',
      lineWidth: 2,
      shadow: false,
      zIndex: 2,
      color: '#000e3e',
      data: [[0, 10], [3,5]],
     name: 'Line for Project 1 - Results'
    
    },{
      dashStyle: 'dash',
      lineWidth: 2,
      shadow: false,
      zIndex: 2,
      color: '#000e3e',
      data: [[0, 5], [3,3]],
     name: 'Line for Project 2 - Results'
    
    },{
      dashStyle: 'dash',
      lineWidth: 2,
      shadow: false,
      zIndex: 2,
      color: '#000e3e',
      data: [[0, 2], [3,0]],
     name: 'Line for Project 3 - Results'
    
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve effect you need is by setting the **x** values of your line series data to floating point number values, instead of integers, for example equal to 0.2 or -0.2. Please take a look on code below:

```
{
  dashStyle: 'dash',
  lineWidth: 2,
  shadow: false,
  zIndex: 2,
  color: '#000e3e',
  data: [[-0.2, 10], [3,5]],
    name: 'Line for Project 1 - Results'
}
```

I prepared a [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/daniel_s/m1n2cv9e/) to show you how it looks.

Best regards!

Comment: Thanks @daniel_s, but what if I want to draw lines from year 2015 or 2016?

Comment: @Babel, If you want to draw lines starting from another years, of course you can. Individual years (in this case categories) has individual values like 0,1,2,3 (indexes), right? However, those are only xAxis values, so you shouldn't use integers. You could use e.g 0.8 value instead of 1, which mean that the Point will be placed little more left than 1 on xAxis.
Here is next JS Fiddle example with my comments, so try to configure it few times, then it shoud become easy to understand for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/daniel_s/gwjbxsnz/

Comment: thanks again for you explanation, I understand it but I have a last question. When I put -1.2 it generates index -1 instead of getting  index 1 and placing it -0.2 on the left?  Like this https://jsfiddle.net/hfzxxeLq/2/#&togetherjs=d8qJ9Lhvhl

Comment: It's normal behaviour. Try to imagine axis with values from 0 to 5 with interval equal to 1. So, you have 0,1,2,3,4,5 ticks on that axis. When you could move some value more to the left side of 1, you've to subtract for example 0.2, so result of 1-0.2 gives 0.8 (not -1.2). I hope, now you understand it better ;)